# Read FieldMultiLineText with REST API query

Tags: rest

Im trying to query data from different lists. Im having the issue, I cannot read a `FieldMultiLineText` field from a list I joined via expand. The server responds

> I t is invalid to query the field.

The fields name in the query below is `,lookupfieldToMyotherlist/mymultilinetextfield`. Without this field the query runs fine.

Is it not possible in Sharepoint 2013 or is there something missing in my query?

```
/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items?$select=Title,lookupfieldToMyotherlist/Title,lookupfieldToMyotherlist/mytextfield,lookupfieldToMyotherlist/mymultilinetextfield&$expand=lookupfieldToMyotherlist
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems SharePoint **2013** REST Interface does not support of getting projected fields of `Note` type, probably due to performance reasons.

Basically there two options available here.

**Option 1**

Perform an additional request to projected List to get field values of `Note` type, for example:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List')/items?$select=JoinList/Id&$expand=JoinList
```

and then get field value of `Note` type:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('JoinList')/items(<itemid>)?$select=Notes
```

where

- `Notes` is a field of Note type
- `itemid` corresponds to `JoinList/Id` value from the first request

**Option 2**

Utilize SharePoint **2010** REST Interface instead, where no such kind limitation exist. The following example demonstrates how to retrieve Note field from lookup list:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/List?$select=JoinList/Notes&$expand=JoinList
```

where

`Notes` is a field of Note type

Comment: Thx for the alternatives. Can you tell me how to utilize the 2010 Interface at SP 2013? When I try to change my query syntax, the server tells me "Resource not found for the segment '#LISTNAME' "

Comment: You could try the following root query `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` to determine list (resource) name (`collection` element in result)

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped and solved my issue. Somehow SP lets any list beginn with a capital letter. This fact and the case-sensitive feature inside the URI caused the error  :)